# Splitting a list and then splitting the last element of that list

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

For my assignment, I have to split a list twice:
I need to split the address string from the input line using ’+’, and then split the last part of the resulting list at the ’,’

```
in_file = open('yelp-short.txt')

def parse_line(text_file):
    a = text_file.strip('\n')
    b = a.split('+')
    c = b.split(',')
    print c
```

I get the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

What other methods could I use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is that you split the *last part* of the resulting list.

Therefore, you want to pull out the last part and split it:

```
def parse_line(line):
    line = line.strip('\n')
    parts = line.split('+')
    addrs = parts[-1].split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would `rpartition`:

```
>>> 'a+b+c,d,e'.rpartition('+')[-1].split(',')
['c', 'd', 'e']
```

The problem is that you are trying to split up a list, not a string. You need to get a particular item out of that list:

```
b = a.split('+')
c = b[-1].split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You apply `split` on strings, and it results in a list. Thus, `a` is a string, `b` is a list. You can't `split` a list. Let's say `a` is `"X+Y,Z"`. `b` will be the list `["X", "Y,Z"]`. What you want to split is the 1st (normal people's 2nd) element of the list `b` - `b[1].split(',')`. This way there is no error. You can also say "last", by saying `b[-1]`. It is the same element.